# Call form's method which is inside a frame

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am developing a software which have a main form and a "content" form.
The content form is inside a frame of the main form.

What I have to do is to call a method of the content form from the main form.

Code from MainWindow.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
  ...
  <Frame x:Name="contentFrame" x:FieldModifier="public" Height="500" Width="600" />
  ...
</StackPanel>
```

Code from MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
contentFrame.Source = new Uri("contentForm.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

What I would like to do:

```
FormInsideFrameInstance.method();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to cast the `Content` property of the `Frame` to whatever the type of the current `Content` is, e.g.:

```
contentForm cf = contentFrame.Content as contentForm;
if (cf != null)
{
    cf.Method();
}
```